# Python custom formula calculator

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have just started learning python and I love the language, it is much easier to understand that the others I have tried in the past, that being said I have been hitting my head against a wall for a few days now.

I am trying to write a custom formula python calc. So far I have:

```
from Tkinter import *
from math import *
def printAll():
    printMoneyIn()
    printMoneyOut()

def printMoneyIn():
    Label(master, text= "money in = \n" u"\xA3").grid(row=7, column=0)
def printMoneyOut():
    Label(master, text = "money out", sum = (e1 + e2 * e3 + e4)).grid(row=8)

master = Tk()
v = IntVar()
formula1 = e1*e2*e3+e4
formula2 = e1+e2+e3+e4

e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)
e3 = Entry(master)
e4 = Entry(master)

def getFloats():
    val1 = float (e1.get())
    val2 = float (e2.get())
    val3 = float (e3.get())
    val4 = float (e4.get())

Radiobutton(master, text="without", padx = 10, width = 10, variable=v, value=1, indicatoron=0).grid(row=1, column=0)
Radiobutton(master, text="with", padx = 10, width = 10, variable=v, value=2, indicatoron=0).grid(row=1, column=1)
Label(master, text="money in", padx=20, width=10, bg = "light blue").grid(row=3)
Label(master, text="times by", padx=20, width=10, bg = "light blue").grid(row=4)
Label(master, text="times by", padx=20, width=10, bg = "red").grid(row=5)
Label(master, text="money out", padx=20, width=10, bg = "red").grid(row=6)
Label(master).grid(row=7, column=0)

# automatically adds the value 5 to money out
e4.insert(10,"5")

e1.grid(row=3, column=1)
e2.grid(row=4, column=1)
e3.grid(row=5, column=1)
e4.grid(row=6, column=1)
Button(master, text='Show', command=printAll, width=20).grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
Label(master).grid(row=7, column=0)
Label(master).grid(row=8)
master.mainloop()
```

My aim is to:

- Add the values in the entry boxes.
- Determine which radio box is selected to determine the formula.
- Run the formula on the numbers in the entry boxes.
- Display the result at the bottom.

No matter what I try I can't seem to get the numbers to interact with each other.

I am scouring the internet and getting more confused than i started. If anyone can point me in the right direction please so I can continue to learn this language.

Thank you for your help.

Rob

Comment: What error are you getting? When you calculate formula1 and formula2 e1, e2, e3, and e4 are not defined...

Comment: So far you have shown what you have done and what you want to achieve, but not what your actual problem is and what specifically you want to know. That would be required to get an answer.

Comment: You haven't asked a question in your question. What _specific_ part of the problem do you need help with?

Comment: specifically i would like to know how to get the numbers from each of the the entry forms, turn them in to floats then run one of the formula (based on the radiobutton) to calculate the answer and place it in the label on row 8. I just dont know where the best place to go to find the answers is. i have trawled google but im getting lost in a loop, thank you for your help so far

Comment: for the first part i cant seem to get my entered values to calcualte in any sort of formula, i thought this was down to the data being entered as text so tried to convert it to a float first but then the numbers add or times eachother (if that makes sense?) sorry I am terribly new at this and thought it would be a good experiment to get my teeth in to. However it is way more complicated than i can fathom alone.

Comment: First step would be to not `import *`. Either import what you need specifically eg `from math import pi` or `import math` and then use `math.pi`. You don't know what variables your modules might need to use that you're overwriting because you've imported them into your script and then overwritten them with your own, without realising those variable names were needed by the module (because you took them from 'in the module's namespace' into your namespace by using `*`). This doesn't happen if you use `math.pi`.

Comment: Cool, A very good start. And great explanation. Thank you I will change that now.

Comment: Please add your question from your comments to your question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things going on in your code that will cause it to not work right.

Even if `printMoneyIn()` and `printMoneyOut()` portions of your code worked it would be stacking labels on top of each other every time you pressed the show button. Instead you should create the label on init and then update that label when you press show. Note that both of your labels will fail because they are not 1 continuous string. If you want to add something to a string you can do that by using `.format()`. Do the math first then append that value to the text field. It should make it easier to read.

There is a problem with converting your entry fields to floats. If the entry fields are blank or contain a non number value it will error. We can fix this a few ways but for now I have added a for loop that will put zero in each field to start with. But down the road you should make sure you have error checking like using a `try/except` statement or with `validation`.

One other thing that you can keep in mind when programing in python is to avoid the use of `*` when importing. Be more exact on what it is you are importing or make sure you don't override any other imported or build in methods by defining what you imported uniquely. For example you can do `import tkinter as tk`. This will let you use any of tkinters methods with the prefix of `tk.` without effecting anything else in the namespace.

Take a look at the below code. Its not perfect but its cleaned up a bit and functional.

```
import tkinter as tk


master = tk.Tk()
v = tk.IntVar()

def printAll():
    val1 = float(e1.get())
    val2 = float(e2.get())
    val3 = float(e3.get())
    val4 = float(e4.get())
    my_sum = (val1 + val2 * val3 + val4)
    lbl1.config(text = "money out = {}".format(my_sum))

tk.Radiobutton(master, text="without", padx = 10, width = 10, variable=v, value=1, indicatoron=0).grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Radiobutton(master, text="with", padx = 10, width = 10, variable=v, value=2, indicatoron=0).grid(row=1, column=1)
tk.Label(master, text="money in", padx=20, width=10, bg = "light blue").grid(row=3)
tk.Label(master, text="times by", padx=20, width=10, bg = "light blue").grid(row=4)
tk.Label(master, text="times by", padx=20, width=10, bg = "red").grid(row=5)
tk.Label(master, text="money out", padx=20, width=10, bg = "red").grid(row=6)

# You need to assign your label widget to a variable name so you can update its text later.
lbl1 = tk.Label(master, text = "money out")
lbl1.grid(row=10)

e1 = tk.Entry(master)
e2 = tk.Entry(master)
e3 = tk.Entry(master)
e4 = tk.Entry(master)
e1.grid(row=3, column=1)
e2.grid(row=4, column=1)
e3.grid(row=5, column=1)
e4.grid(row=6, column=1)

# automatically adds zeros to all fields. Because you cannot convert blank fields to floats.
for entry in [e1, e2, e3, e4]:
    entry.insert(tk.END, "0") 

tk.Button(master, text='Show', command=printAll, width=20).grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Mike, that is perfect, thank you, a really great contribution which is greatly appreciated and I can can really roll with it now I can see the code. I will be looking in to that validation but for now thank you for your help.

Comment: @Rob Glad to help. You might benefit from reading up on some of the documentation for tkinter. They have a lot of information on how to use each widget and what you can do with them.